# BootStrap css is not working having showHeader="True"

Tags: apex, visualforce, page-layout, bootstrap

I create a VF page using the BootStrap CSS library and everything works just fine if the showHeader  is equals FALSE. But If I try to include bootstrap in a vf page with showHeader="True" salesforce styles will get messed up.
I am not using pageblock, just html, and some apex:outputText fields

Any ideas? I will appreciate any help.

Here are the attributes of the

```
   <apex:page controller="dashBoardPOIssues"  showheader="true" standardStylesheets="false"  doctype="html-5.0">
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're entering a world of pain there... :)

If you really want to use bootstrap AND retain the salesforce header and the styling that goes with it, consider using 'Visualstrap' which is on the Appexchange at this [link](https://appexchange.salesforce.com/listingDetail?listingId=a0N3000000B56AMEAZ).

[image]

Comment: CloudHugger, thank you for the info. You are right it is a pain:)

Answer (score 8):

If you don't want to download Visualstrap, you can add a namespace to your bootstrap.

A guy at Dreamforce did a tutorial on it:

http://bracketlabs.com/blog/2014/1/20/bracket-labs-dreamforce-roundup-visualforce-and-bootstrap

1. Basically, you download the bootstrap source.
2. Find bootstrap.less
3. Surround whole document with .bs { }
4. Recompile
5. Add to SalesForce

Comment: which editor I use to compile It after adding the namespace